# Python server to Oracle database

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I've been connected to Oracle DB with my local PC with below code.

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect("user/pw@host:port/service_name")
cur = con.cursor()
```

Now I can use python server, I wanted to do the same work at python server.

I'm confused whether I should install Oracle Client at Python server, as I did at my local PC. Because the same code didn't work at the python server. Error message was shown as below.

```
DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what a 'Python server' is, but from the error message you need to install the 64-bit Oracle client libraries and make sure that your system library search path includes them.  The message gives a link with steps that you can follow, or you can use the [cx_Oracle installation instructions](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html).

There's an [architecture diagram in the cx_Oracle documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/introduction.html) that may be useful.

Was there something that was confusing in the DPI error message?  Can you suggest improvements to it?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to install python - oracle dependencies for your connection to work